# In 7 Wonders Duel: Pantheon, the "Ra" Divinity card lets you steal one Wonder from an opponent; do you choose, or is it random?

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

In *7 Wonders Duel: Pantheon*, the Divinity card Ra takes away one Wonder from your opponent, but it is not clear in the rules if you can choose or have to randomly draw or the opponent decides which one they are giving to you. Does anyone has clarification on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe 'Steal' will mean of your choice.

I've taken screen shots here of rules from Pantheon and Agora with Agora on top.  It's using the Baal god rather that Ra but it still uses the word 'steal.  Unfortunately the 'steal a wonder' icon isn't in agora hence using Baal to answer this question about terminology instead.

[image: image from Agora with says take of your choice]
[image: Baal god using word steal]

Both these descriptions use exactly the same icon.  In Agora rules it it clarified that the taking is 'of your choice'.  I think it would be very confusing for a player looking at the same icon in a different expansion and assuming it was random pick.

Comment: I've just realised my problem today. We always played with our wonders hidden until played. But just checked in the rulebook, they should be visible on the table always. So basically, you steal one from your opponent's visible non-built wonders so it now makes total sense.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad you spotted the issue.  Why did you have wonders hidden when they are drafted face up?

Comment: I don't know why, we have been playing this game for more than one and a half years now, but did this since the beginning. It will add a change to our game-flow so actually nice :)

Comment: All of us will have 'that rule we got wrong for years'. I was playing Snowdonia wrong for about 10 years.

Answer (score 3):

I have no official answer, but the rules say:

> Steal an opponent's Wonder which has not yet been constructed; it is added to your own Wonders.

Since you are "stealing", you get to decide what you take - at least, this is how I've played it up until now.

Comment: This ability seems to be very powerful anyway so we opted in our house rules as randomly chosen out of the available ones, but your explanation also makes sense. Would be good to see a definitive answer on it.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation on Board Game Arena lets Ra's user choose which wonder to steal, so I think we can be pretty sure that that is indeed the intended effect.